# Difference between Gabor filter implementations

Tags: image-processing, gabor

I was reading a paper and came across this:

[image: Gabor magnitude pictures]

I'd like to implement this in matlab, therefore I initially searched for a premade implementation. I stumbled upon this: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/5237-2d-gabor-filterver123 .
Though they use a different equation. My question now is: what is the difference between this equation and the one from the paper I read ?

Comment: I'm not that there is a difference. What exactly are you referring to?

Comment: Well it seems to me that they are using different equations. The paper is using the one that I put in the post above, and the matlab code found on mathworks uses a different equation I think (you can see the equation in the comments of the code).

Comment: OK, I was looking at the wrong thing, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both equations are related by Euler's formula: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula
They are mathematically equivalent, it's well explained on the Wikipedia page.

In a practical point of view, $\cos(x)+i\sin(x)$ allows for easy separation of real and imaginary. On the other hand, $\exp(ix)$ makes it easier to deal with Gaussian since $\exp(x)\cdot\exp(y)=\exp(x+y)$.

Hope this helps!